# Subplot of Subplots Matplotlib / Seaborn

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to create a grid of subplots. each subplot will look like the one that is on this site.

https://python-graph-gallery.com/24-histogram-with-a-boxplot-on-top-seaborn/

If I have 10 different sets of this style of plot I want to make them into a 5x2 for example.

I have read through the documentation of Matplotlib and cannot seem to figure out how do it. I can loop the subplots and have each output but I cannot make it into the rows and columns

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 10)),columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))

for c in df :
    # Cut the window in 2 parts
    f, (ax_box,
        ax_hist) = plt.subplots(2,
                                sharex=True,
                                gridspec_kw={"height_ratios":(.15, .85)},
                                figsize = (10, 10))
    # Add a graph in each part
    sns.boxplot(df[c], ax=ax_box)
    ax_hist.hist(df[c])
    # Remove x axis name for the boxplot
plt.show()
```

the results would just take this loop and put them into a set of rows and columns in this case 5x2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have 10 columns, each of which creates 2 subplots: a box plot and a histogram. So you need a total of 20 figures. You can do this by creating a grid of 2 rows and 10 columns

---

**Complete answer:** (Adjust the `figsize` and `height_ratios` as per taste)

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f, axes = plt.subplots(2, 10, sharex=True, gridspec_kw={"height_ratios":(.35, .35)}, 
                                    figsize = (12, 5))

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 10)),columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))

for i, c in enumerate(df):
    sns.boxplot(df[c], ax=axes[0,i])
    axes[1,i].hist(df[c])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: this was perfect. I just changed the shares = False so that only the corresponding box plot and histogram share an x not all of them. This seemed to work for me